# How Does One Install an HP 4250 Printer connectedVia a JetDirect 620N Print-Server-Card to the LAN?

Tags: windows-8, printing

The end user workstation is Window 8-64bit. The 4250 is connected to the LAN with a JetDirect 620N (as shown here: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Home.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=378355&lang=en&cc=us).

How can it be installed so that the user can print from their workstation?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  IS the 620N configured and can others print to the printer?

Comment: it seems to have configured itself (or perhaps after I ran the installer locally).

Answer (score 0):

Download the driver shown here: http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareIndex.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&prodNameId=412158&prodTypeId=18972&prodSeriesId=412144&swLang=8&taskId=135&swEnvOID=4132

(left out of this answer is whether it is the PCL6 or postscript?--either seems to work)